# Why is New Relic advertisement sticky?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

10 out 10 refresh/page change on UL have the New Relic advertisement in the sidebar. Seems like the normal Community ads, and non-community ones aren't appearing at all.

Is this really expected?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour at this time. Of approximately 20 refreshes that I did, I got a very random distribution of ads. I also visited new relic via their ad which seemed to make their advertisement appear more often (1 in 2-3 reloads) but I cannot get it to reliably appear each time.

**EDIT**

My colleague Anna's contribution to this answer: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25

Answer (score 5):

This is simply a result of New Relic purchasing a large share-of-voice, 25%, of available inventory. 25% is currently the maximum we're allowing any single advertiser to purchase at one time on the sites outside of the trilogy.

Note: retargeting is not something we currently permit from paid advertisers.

Comment: Your answer and your profile would suggest that you work for SE. If so, could you please mention that explicitly in your answer? You don't have a diamond so it looks like you're just some random user commenting instead of the person best suited to answer.

Comment: @terdon he has diamond on mSE. Not all SE employees have diamonds network-wide.

Comment: Sorry @terdon, I just expected my diamond to migrate with me. I'll have that fixed in a jiffy! :-)

Comment: There we go. Also, I can't believe I said "fixed in a jiffy."